# I'm learning python, and I can't figure out what's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I said in the title. When I try to run it, it shows the following.
 Line 30: SyntaxError: bad input ('
')
The code referenced above is below. I just need a little blurb here to make it so I can post this.

```
 #Samuel Davis, module 3 exam, 12/9/19

    #Declare variables    

    dayPay = 18.50 
    evePay = 20.00
    nightPay = 23.50
    retire = 0.02



    #Prompt inputs from user

    employeeShift = int(input("What shift do you work? 1=Day 2=evening 3=night."))
    weekHour = int(input("How many hours did you work this week?"))

    #Begin prep

    if grossShift==1:
        employeePay=dayPay*weekHour    
    elif employeeShift==2:
        grossPay=evePay*weekHour
    elif employeeshift==3:
        grossPay=nightPay*weekHour
    else: 
        employeePay=0

    #Finalize calculations & get retirement deduction

    if employeeShift==1
        retireDed=0
        print("You cannot get a retirement deduction in the day shift")
    else
        retireDed=employeePay*retire

    netPay=employeepay-retireDed

    print(totalPay)
```

Comment: employeeShift won't be used in actual calculations, it's just to identify which shift the supposed employee did.

Comment: alright, I did so, but that's not making the code work still.

Comment: If you input `3` for `employeeShift` then `employeePay` is not defined, which will cause `print(employeePay)` to raise a `NameError`

Comment: It's showing the same error as I put into the text. Line 30: SyntaxError: bad input (' ')

Comment: The error says "line 30". You did not post 30 lines of codes. Help us to help you. As it stands now, the code you posted contains no errors (except for the use case I mentioned)

Comment: oops. hold on. sorry, I didn't think about that.

Comment: It highlights the line "if employeeShift==1"

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors/undeclared variables. I've tried my best to re-construct/edit what I think you're going for to have at least a functioning script:

```
#Declare variables    
dayPay = 18.50 
evePay = 20.00
nightPay = 23.50
retire = 0.02

#Prompt inputs from user
employeeShift = int(input("What shift do you work? 1=Day 2=evening 3=night."))
weekHour = int(input("How many hours did you work this week?"))

#Begin prep
if employeeShift==1:
    employeePay=dayPay*weekHour    
elif employeeShift==2:
    grossPay=evePay*weekHour
elif employeeshift==3:
    grossPay=nightPay*weekHour
else: 
    employeePay=0

#Finalize calculations & get retirement deduction
if employeeShift==1:
    retireDed=0
    print("You cannot get a retirement deduction in the day shift")
else:
    retireDed=employeePay*retire
netPay=employeePay-retireDed
print(netPay)
```